# 3D Geometry projecting a point in space to an image given FOV and angles

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry

I'm attempting to project a 3D point in Cartesian space onto an image, so it is shown as a circle at the location on the image it would be seen if a certain camera was looking at it.

Knows:
The camera has horizontal field of view, vertical FOV, azimuth and elevation.
It is located at (0,0,0) although being able to change this would be good.
The image has a certain size.
The point in space has a know X, Y, Z location.

I'm using the very good C++ library [MathGeoLib](http://clb.demon.fi/MathGeoLib/nightly/)

In my attempt, changing azimuth or elevation does not work, but the projection seems to work ok if rotation is ignored.

How do you convert from a real world point into pixel location of an image providing that you know where the where the camera is, which direction it is looking and it's field of view?

```
Frustum MyClass::GetCameraFrustrum()
{
  Frustum frustrum;
  frustrum.SetPerspective(DegToRad(_horizontal_field_of_view), DegToRad(_vertical_filed_of_view));
  // Looking straight down the z axis
  frustrum.SetFront(vec(0, 0, 1));
  frustrum.SetUp(vec(0, 1, 0));
  frustrum.SetPos(vec(0,0,0));
  frustrum.SetKind(FrustumSpaceGL, FrustumRightHanded);

  frustrum.SetViewPlaneDistances(1, 2000);
  float3x3 rotate_around_x = float3x3::RotateX(DegToRad(_angle_azimuth));
  frustrum.Transform(rotate_around_x);

  float3x3 rotate_around_y = float3x3::RotateY(DegToRad(_angle_elevation));
  frustrum.Transform(rotate_around_y);
  return frustrum;
}

void MyClass::Test()
{
  cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(2000, 2000, CV_8UC1);
  Frustum camera_frustrum = GetCameraFrustrum();
  vec projection = camera_frustrum.Project(_position_of_object);

  cv::Point2d location_on_image(projection.x * image.cols, projection.y * image.rows);

  LOG_DEBUG << location_on_image;
  cv::circle(image, location_on_image, 5, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3, cv::LINE_AA);
}
```

Comment: I just typed a long answer and then realized i did not understand the question. could you add a "is" vs. "should" screenshot?

Comment: also you are confused about projection matrices: you never rotate those! in 3d you usually have two matrices: one that handles moving and rotating stuff (model-view) and one for projection (perspective). It will kind of work for a bit to munge the two together - but then you get problems.

Comment: So how do you go about converting from real world coordinates into what a camera would see, provided you know what it's location, field of view and orientation is?